# Why isn't the datagrid horizontal scroll showing in my WPF app?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

In my WPF app I have multiple datagrid's, but none of them are showing the horizontal scroll for scrolling the datagrid data horizontally, the vertical scroll is there as it should.

Here is the styling for datagrid that I've implemented:

```
<Window.Resources>

<!--Datagrid style-->
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#AA00FF" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold" />
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
<Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="*"></Setter>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"></Setter>
</Style>
<!--Selected row color-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#DCE775" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#01579B" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="DemiBold" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<!-- Scroll style -->
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarCustomThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Fill="Transparent" />
<Border x:Name="CornerScrollBarRectangle" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="0,1,0,1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
<Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"  Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
<Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle"  Property="Height" Value="6" />
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
<Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F6A55D" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="7" />

<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
<Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="true" Focusable="false">
<Track.Thumb>
<Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarCustomThumb}" />
</Track.Thumb>
<Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
<RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
</Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
<Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
<RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
</Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
</Track>
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<Trigger SourceName="Thumb"  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
<Setter Value="#84FFFF" TargetName="Thumb"  Property="Background" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger SourceName="Thumb"  Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
<Setter Value="#18FFFF" TargetName="Thumb"  Property="Background" />
</Trigger>

<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
<Setter TargetName="Thumb"  Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
<Setter TargetName="GridRoot" Property="LayoutTransform">
<Setter.Value>
<RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="LayoutTransform">
<Setter.Value>
<RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="8" />
<Setter TargetName="Thumb" Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal" />
<Setter TargetName="PageDown" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand" />
<Setter TargetName="PageUp" Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand" />
</Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

The actual datagrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Background="#212121"
    RowBackground="#212121"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#000000"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    Foreground="White"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    CanUserAddRows="false"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="10,0,5,5"
    Name="realized"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
    VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7C4DFF" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

and

```
<DataGrid BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="#212121"
    RowBackground="#212121"
    AlternatingRowBackground="#000000"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    Foreground="White"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    SelectionUnit="FullRow"
    x:Name="dg"
    Margin="10,0,10,10"
    Padding="10" />
```

Is there anything in the styling that is preventing the horizontal scroll from showing ? If so, how do I fix that?

[image: img]

The code for the 3rd tabitem in the tabcontrol

```
<TabItem Header="Item3" Name="tabItem3" Background="#2e2e00" Foreground="White"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             FontFamily="Leelawadee UI" FontSize="20" Margin="-45,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" >
                        <Border Background="#2e2e00" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=grid,Path=ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=ActualHeight}" >
                            <Grid Margin="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGrid BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                RowBackground="#E53935"
                                AlternatingRowBackground="#C2185B"
                                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                Foreground="#B2FF59"
                                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                                GridLinesVisibility="None"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                CanUserAddRows="False"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                x:Name="dg2"
                                Margin="10,0,10,10"
                                Padding="10" >
                                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#673AB7" />
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#C0CA33" />
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="DemiBold" />
                                                </Trigger>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                                </Trigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                                    
                                </DataGrid>
                                <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Width="300" Height="25"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </TabItem>
```

Comment: Do you see the scrollbar if you remove your custom style(s)? Then you know where the problem is.

Comment: @mm8 I do see the horizontal scrollbar if I remove the `scroll style` from the XAML but I cannot scroll in that for some reason...Also, when I apply the `scroll style` I can see and use the vertical scroll but why not the horizontal one?

Comment: Is the contents horizontally scrollable at all? I would need a full example to be able to help you out.

Comment: @mm8 The column contents are cut/overlapped ... I've added an image for better understanding how it looks.

Comment: Doesn't help much.

Comment: @mm8 I've also added the code inside the last TabItem where the Datagrid in the image resides. Hope it helps...